# Unable to run delayed job at specific time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have a job file and I am using delayed_job driver for rails.

It works fine for perform later.

My job file:
**jobs/test_job_job.rb**

```
class TestJobJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args)
    puts("test")
  end
  def test_method
    puts('test method')
  end
end
```

In my controller, I did,

```
TestJobJob.perform_later
```

It worked fine and gave me right output:
Output:

```
[Worker(host:hunter pid:8079)] Job ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper (id=18) RUNNING
test
[Worker(host:hunter pid:8079)] Job ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper (id=18) COMPLETED after 0.0397
[Worker(host:hunter pid:8079)] 1 jobs processed at 1.3259 j/s, 0 failed
```

But when I changed to,

```
TestJobJob.delay(run_at: 2.minutes.from_now)
```

Job was not even en-queued, and when I did,

```
TestJobJob.delay(run_at: 2.minutes.from_now).test_method
```

It gave me error: undefined method `test_method' for TestJobJob

My config:application.rb

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
```

Comment: What do you mean by "was not even enqueued?"

Comment: means the job didn't insert in database

Comment: So what is the rails log for `TestJobJob.delay(run_at: 2.minutes.from_now)`